# AWS API Gateway failed with: Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I try to get my data from dynamodb using API-Gateway. It works with other functions that are relatively similar. If I work without "**json.dumps()**" I get Malformed exception, but in the Logs are the data from the table, otherwise, I get this exception (without any data):

> Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function
>   error: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

This is my python-code

```
import json
import boto3
from decimal import Decimal

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
tablename = dynamodb.Table('db')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   query = event["queryStringParameters"]['email']
   #query = event['query']

   response = tablename.scan(
      FilterExpression=Attr('email').eq(query))
   items = response['Items']

   return{
      "isBase64Encoded": False,
      "statusCode": 200,
      "body" : json.dumps(items)
   }
```

This code for another table works fine:

```
import json
import boto3
from decimal import Decimal

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
tablename = dynamodb.Table('FOODGER')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

   query = event["queryStringParameters"]['query']
   #query = event['query']

   response = tablename.scan(
      FilterExpression=Attr('generic food.name').begins_with(query.title()))
   items = response['Items']

   return{
      "isBase64Encoded": False,
      "statusCode": 200,
      "body" : json.dumps(items)
   }
```

Comment: You have to cast decimal to float. Before json dump.